# Matrix with 1d vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, return

I represent a n*m matrix like chessboard.

1  0  2  0

0  3  0  4

5  0  6  0

0  7  0  8

I don't need to store the zeros in my 1d vector.

> vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4.. etc}

I ask the user for a row and column number.
How can i return with i. row j. column element?

> if (i+j) % 2 != 0

I return with 0, but i don't know what i need to do when

> (i+j) % 2 == 0

Can you help me? (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Why chessboard when in chess, we use all cases, checker-game only uses cases of one specific color.

Answer (score 4):

With regular matrices stored as 1D-vector, coordinate to index would be:

`(i + j * width)` (or `i * height + j` depending on convention).

with half case to 0, you just have to divide by 2:

```
if ((i + j) % 2 != 0) return 0;
else return data[(i + j * width) / 2];
```

Comment: @Caleth: No. it should work for even or odd width.

Comment: And can you help me how can I multiply 2 matrix like this? 
I deduced it on paper but I didn’t figure out the logic :(

Comment: @PuN1Sh3r: You should probably ask another question for that.